# bootstrap - box shadow is bigger than input field

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

I have added glow effect for my form fields

```
textarea:focus, input:focus, .uneditable-input:focus {   
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(82, 174, 255, 0.075) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(82, 174, 255, 0.6) !important;
    outline: 0 none !important;
}

.has-error {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(218, 21,17, 0.075) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(218, 21,17, 0.6) !important;
}
```

HTML

```html
<div class="form-group required">
<label for="first_name" class="control-label col-lg-3 col-sm-4">First name 1<span class="req-marker">|</span></label>
<div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-8">
<input required="true" class="form-control" id="first_name" type="text" name="first_name" value="">
</div>
</div>
```

If required field is empty I want to add the glow to .has-error class hence added box-shadow.But, as you can see in attached image, shadow is bigger than original input field.

Comment: Can you post the input related HTML code?

Comment: It seems to work: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ok0z8fh/).

Comment: I as applying the has-error on div...Thank you now it's solved